# Applications of large graph layout

Tags: graph

I've been playing with large graph layout for a while now.  What are some applications for the layout, visualization, and interaction with large graphs?  Large in this case meaning at least 10's of thousands of nodes.

I'd like to find something that doesn't just look cool but is actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Tulip](http://tulip.labri.fr/TulipDrupal/) is designed to visualize huge graphs, some of the screenshots might give you ideas for applications. There is also a similar conversation, but in reverse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243616/visualization-tools-for-huge-graphs). There the question is which existing tools are best for huge graphs. The post by Scott has a number of links which might contain useful galleries.

Answer (score 0):

the best tools for large graphs are mental mathematical tools from topology and differential geometry such as fiber bundles, ricci flows or manifold surgery as well as dimensional reduction via either compression techniques or linear algebraic methods. anyone who sits there drawing a zillion nodes and edges without any analysis of structural redundancy is just basically trying to make pretty pictures with no purpose or understanding.